# Font size in leaflet-measure-path library

Tags: angular, leaflet

I am using leaflet in an angular project with the library [leaflet-measure-path](https://github.com/ProminentEdge/leaflet-measure-path) to show distances and other values of my draws. I am trying to modify the font size of numbers but I do not find the way to do it applying styles over the div of map directly.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: How did you get it to work with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the font size in the css or overwrite the style:

```
.leaflet-measure-path-measurement {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

If the new font size is not applied, try it with `!important`:

```
.leaflet-measure-path-measurement {
    font-size: 18px !important;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thanks :)